# What is the value of x in the given puzzle?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

> What is the value of x in the given puzzle?

So many tries, I still haven't got the right answer.
Is there any mistake in the puzzle?

Our teacher gave it us. He was asked by another teacher.

[image: pic[1]]

Plain-text:

```
  
   \      |      /
    \  3  |  x  /
     \    |    /
      \   |   /
       \  |  /
  584   \ | /   33
         \|/
----------------------
         /|\
  399   / | \   84
       /  |  \
      /   |   \
     /    |    \
    / 258 | 155 \
   /      |      \
```

Comment: It looks like this : https://oeis.org/A027444. Since you asked if there was any mistake, well, maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> 14. The sequence **should** be: $3,14,39,84,155,258,399,584$, which is $n^3+n^2+n$, but the teacher made a mistake and wrote $33$ instead of $39$.